# Is it safe to declare function prototypes for functions that do not exist?

Tags: c, gcc

I am writing a C program that uses some macros that make function prototypes in batches, however I often don't write all of the functions the macro makes prototypes for. This compiles fine in gcc, but I'm wondering if this is unsafe in any way or if it will cause errors if I use a different compiler?

Comment: If you declare, don't define, and then use a function, you get a linker-error. If you declare, don't define, and don't use a function, there's no problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The prototypes only declare the name and use (parameters, types) of functions. If the compiler encounters a use of such a function, it will check your use against the prototype and warn if your use is not compatible.

When the development environment starts linking the objects, it will search for functions used but not found in the object. Linking fails if a function that is used is not found.

Since the prototype only declares the function and its usage, it does not require the function to be present IF the function is not used. Hence it is safe to declare prototypes for functions that you don't provide.

(But it could be confusing for another programmer who will expect the function to exists if he/she sees the prototype.)

Comment: That last sentence should be in **bold**. Allowed or not, it's bad form to declare functions that don't exist. It's confusing to other programmers, and also to yourself six months later.

Comment: Note also that a function is "used" even if the call to it is inside a branch that you expect to be removed by constant-propagation and dead code removal. The only way this is legal is if the function is never referenced at all except for the declaration(s).

Comment: @R, if the call is removed, then the compiler might not put the function in the table of unresolved symbols, so as far as the linker is concerned, it is not used (the linker will not even know about it).